# Python custom JSON encoder isn't handling numpy NaN or Infinite values

Tags: python, json, numpy, python-3.6

So I'm trying to write a custom encoder that handles different `numpy` values:

```
class NumpyEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        if np.isnan(obj) or np.isinf(obj):
            return None
        else:
            return super().default(obj)
```

However, it doesn't appear to be handling `np.NaN` or `np.inf` objects:

```
obj = {'test': np.NaN, 'test2': np.inf}
json.dumps(obj, cls=LazyNumpyEncoder)
Out[5]: '{"test": NaN, "test2": Infinity}'
```

I've also tried using `elif isinstance(obj, np.nan):`, but that hasn't worked either.

What I want is my `NaN` and Infinite (including negative infinite values) to be turned into nulls.

Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: `np.nan` probably satisfies the `float` test.

Comment: @hpaulj it doesn't

Comment: I tried that as well, (since I know `nan` and `infinite` are special float values). But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason here is that `default` method can be used only to make *new* types serializable. It can't be used to override serializing of types, already defined in `json`. Here's what the docstring of `JSONEncoder` says (emphasis mine):

> To extend this to *recognize other objects*, subclass and implement a `.default()` method with another method that returns a serializable object for `o` if possible, otherwise it should call the superclass implementation (to raise `TypeError`).

If you look at the sources, you'll notice that `default` is called after all other serialization attempts fail. So the code in OP post doesn't get called. In accordance with the above citation, `DjangoJSONEncoder` implements `default` to make it understand date/time, decimal types, and UUIDs.

As for how to work around this - well, I wouldn't bother with subclassing but rather go down the dict recursively (beware loops!) and replace NaNs and Infs with `None` before passing the dict into `json.dumps`. It is also possible to use `json.dumps(..., allow_nan=False)` to make sure all NaNs are caught before invoking dumps.

Another option - subclass `JSONEncoder` / `DjangoJSONEncoder`, override `dumps`, insert the algorithm mentioned above and pass rest of the work to a parent class.

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation!

Answer (score 5):

So @Vovanrock explained it super well, but I'll post what I did to fix the problem. Before running the dict through `dumps` I simply converted the `inf` and `nan` objects to strings:

```
def _convert_numpy_objects(self, dict_to_convert : Dict) -> Dict:
    new = {}
    for k, v in dict_to_convert.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new[k] = self._convert_numpy_objects(v)
        else:
            if isinstance(v, float) and (np.isnan(v) or np.isinf(v)):
                new[k] = str(v)
            else:
                new[k] = v
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is list and tuple type data in my dictionary, I changed @Darkstarone code a bit.

```
from typing import Dict

import numpy as np


def _convert_numpy_objects(self, dict_to_convert: Dict) -> Dict:
    new = {}

    for k, v in dict_to_convert.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new[k] = self._convert_numpy_objects(v)
        elif isinstance(v, (list, tuple, set)):
            new[k] = [self._convert_numpy_objects(e) for e in v if isinstance(e, dict)]
        else:
            if isinstance(v, float) and (np.isnan(v) or np.isinf(v)):
                new[k] = str(v)
            else:
                new[k] = v
    return new
```